# R function times() from package chron strange formatting

Tags: r, chron

The very simply operation "times(3/24)" with the times function from package chron leads to:

```
> times(3/24)  
[1] 03:00:00
```

When I use it in a data frame it doesn't lead to the right format. Instead it writes the original number "0.125". However, when I include it in an ifelse() Statement, it works.

See example:

```
> X<-seq(1,10,1)  
> tdata<-as.data.frame(X)  
> tdata$T3AM<-times(3/24)  
> tdata$T3AMx<-times(ifelse(tdata$X>0,3/24,3/24))  
> tdata  
    X  T3AM    T3AMx  
1   1 0.125 03:00:00  
2   2 0.125 03:00:00  
3   3 0.125 03:00:00  
4   4 0.125 03:00:00  
5   5 0.125 03:00:00  
6   6 0.125 03:00:00  
7   7 0.125 03:00:00  
8   8 0.125 03:00:00  
9   9 0.125 03:00:00  
10 10 0.125 03:00:00
```

Is there any explanation for that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"times"` class in chron does not supply a `rep` method.  If we add one then it works.

```
library(chron)
rep.times <- function(x, ...) times(rep(as.numeric(x), ...))

# from question:    
X <- seq(1,10,1)
tdata <- as.data.frame(X)
tdata$T3AM <- times(3/24)
tdata$T3AMx <- times(ifelse(tdata$X>0,3/24,3/24))
```

giving:

```
> tdata  
    X     T3AM    T3AMx
1   1 03:00:00 03:00:00
2   2 03:00:00 03:00:00
3   3 03:00:00 03:00:00
4   4 03:00:00 03:00:00
5   5 03:00:00 03:00:00
6   6 03:00:00 03:00:00
7   7 03:00:00 03:00:00
8   8 03:00:00 03:00:00
9   9 03:00:00 03:00:00
10 10 03:00:00 03:00:00
```

Note that Kurt just added `rep.times` to chron 2.3-53 which should be on CRAN now.